# How do I preserve tags when filtering a repository?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Is there a way to move a repository, **and all its tags**, to be a subdirectory of another repository in an automated fashion?

For reasons, a project was split into multiple repositories.  Now we see that wasn't such a hot idea and want to bring it back together again.  Submodules were considered, but they really are one project and we need to move a lot of files between them.

Let's say we have repository A, B and C.  And we want one project with each of them as a subdirectory:

```
project/
    A/
    B/
    C/
```

That can be accomplished with `git-filter-branch --tree-filter`.  Done, no problem.  And it even does the branches correctly too, which was a pleasant surprise.

The trouble is, A, B and C have tags, and they all need to be converted, too.

Can this be automated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I can answer my own question.  Adding `--tag-name-filter cat` to the `git-filter-branch` call.  `-- --all` does all the branches and tags at once speeding up the conversion considerably.  Here's the full call.

```
 git filter-branch --tree-filter 'move-to-subdir $subdir' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

With move-to-subdir being a little program I wrote to make the subdirectory and move the files into it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Path::Class;
use autodie;

my $subdir = shift;

mkdir $subdir unless -d $subdir;

my $cwd = dir(".");
my @kids = grep { $_ ne $subdir } $cwd->children;
for my $dir (@kids) {
    rename $dir, dir("$subdir/$dir")->cleanup;
}
```

This information is all in the git-filter-branch man page, but it's kind of obscured.